# Transition UIPanGesture to UITableView Scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView` and `UITableView` below it in my view controller, setup with auto layout constraints. I looks something like this:

[image]

I want to drag the `UITableView` up and then seamlessly transition the drag motion into table view scrolling. So it ends up like this:

[image]

I have been using `UIPanGestureRecogniser` to achieve the drag up, adjusting the top views 'top' constraint to have it slide off screen and the table move up. However, I don't know how to pass the touch to the table view or find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass any touches to the table when u're doing the pan ,  simply stretch the table by giving it a constant height if it's cells are static or to any a higher constant (say 1000 ) if it's height dynamic (in the dynamic case after you stretch it with the higher number get last cell bound and resign the correct height) , this way as you pan above , the table automatically scroll